# Pop() used in a comprehension list not removing all items from initial list

Tags: python, list

I have a list and want to make a new one with some computations. 
While doing it, I have met this problem:

Why pop() doesn't remove all items at once from the list ?

```
>>> a= list(range(20))
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>>> [a.pop() for elem in a]
[19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10]
>>> [a.pop() for elem in a]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5]
>>> [a.pop() for elem in a]
[4, 3, 2]
>>> [a.pop() for elem in a]
[1]
```

What I expect is

```
>>> a= list(range(20))
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>>> [a.pop() for elem in a]
[19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Can anybody explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run the same code with for loop instead a list comprehension, you will find your explanation:

```
for ele in a:
    print(ele)
    print("Pop : ",a.pop())
```

Ouput will be :

```
0           # <-- First element, first run  
Pop :  19   # <-- Last element, removed 19, now list contains elements [0,1,----,18]
1
Pop :  18
2
Pop :  17
3
Pop :  16
4
Pop :  15
5
Pop :  14
6
Pop :  13
7
Pop :  12
8
Pop :  11
9          # <--- At this moment the list contain elements [0,1,2,3----,10]
Pop :  10  # <--- Last element removed, Now list has iterated to all its elements.
```

So, when you are poping elements from the same list, it is also shortening the size of that list. Hence it will not remove all the elements at once.

Comment: Yes, that's what I understood when I made a function to reproduce list comprehension ! List comprehension takes the items from the beginning while pop takes them by the end of the list...

Answer (score 5):

The loop, `for item in a`, loops over the index from 0 until the end of the list is reached. During that loop, you are decreasing the list length by calling `pop()`. So if the list is 20 items, after looping through 10 items the list will have become length 10, and the loop stops. You only loop for a number of times equal to half the list's original length.

So the first time, half of 20 is 10. Then half of 10 is 5. Then half of 5 is 3 (after looping twice the end isn't reached yet), then the list length is 5-3=2 and half of that is 1. You are left with a list of length 1, `[0]`.

Yet another special case of the golden rule, **don't mutate a list while iterating over it**.

Comment: Your explanation helped me understand ;-) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

now the behaviour is explained, to get what you expect is to do

```
>>> [a.pop() for el in range(20)]
[19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Or simply: `a.reverse()`

Comment: I guess he wants OP and not list reversed :/

Comment: What you mean by "OP"?